# Getting ValueError rending my Django CreateView

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render out my generic create view for django and I cannot do so as I am getting the error "ValueError at /teacher/add/"       "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'add'." I am not sure what the problem would be here.

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = [
    ('Social Studies', 'Social Studies'),
    ('Math', 'Math'),
    ('Science', 'Science'),
]


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # delete dept == delete teacher
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tenure = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} teaches {self.department}'

    # dont need success url if get_absolute_url on create and update view

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('teacher/add/', TeacherCreateView.as_view(), name='teacher-add'),
]
```

views.py

```
class TeacherCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Teacher
    fields = ['name']
```

Comment: You likely have another URL pattern before the `teacher-add`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have another URL pattern *before* the `TeacherCreateView` that captures the `add`, and thus will fire a different view. This could for example look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('teacher/<pk>/', TeacherDetailView.as_view(), name='teacher'),
    # …,
    path('teacher/add/', TeacherCreateView.as_view(), name='teacher-add'),
    # …
]
```

as a result `<pk>` will capture `add` and thus fire the `DetailView` instead. You should make the `pk` more restrictive and work with an `<int:…>` path converter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('teacher/<int:pk>/', TeacherDetailView.as_view(), name='teacher'),
    # …
    path('teacher/add/', TeacherCreateView.as_view(), name='teacher-add'),
    # …
]
```